# Django - can someone explain saving model info to a db works in a MVC framework?

Tags: django, database, post, model-view-controller, model

So I have a model class a form class and a views class.

I am having a hard time effectively explaining to someone how it works in the sense of a MVC framework. I am new to django and I have followed the documentation however, i cannot seem to explain it well enough.

To my understanding you create the model, which you pass into your form to create a form, then pass that into your view when you render onto an html page through context then you wait for a user to hit a submit button which returns the info via POST and then you catch that data in your view and go through the necessary steps to save the data. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

In python models.py and the forms together are the controller in MVC since they contain the program logic and control saving objects in the DB, views.py file is showing the content of data, so it's the View. The Model is what django ORM handles for us. It stores the data and handles load/stores in the DB.

Comment: but I would argue that the view is the controller because the view has a lot more logic than the models or form file

Comment: You are right. I think we can consider the HTML pages the view, and the rest of the program the model. Forms in some cases can be a part of the view as well. The ones that are being used to display data. I guess we can say that there is no general rule about it, based on what we used things for they can be a part of the MVC model.

Comment: okay cool that helps. So how would you explaion how data is transfered from the model to the form and then to the view eventually the user then types something in and its sent back into the pipeline and stored into a db. and that makes sense to me its just i cannot seem to explain that concept concise enough for it to make sense to others. can you type up how it works in your words? maybe I just dont understand it well enough